# JavaEE Class Annotation Processing on EJBs

Tags: jakarta-ee, annotations, ejb

Can someone tell me how Class Annotations (like Interceptor) are processed on protected or private Methods?

If I have an EJB like this:

```
@Stateless
@Interceptors({ SomeInterceptor.class })
public class ContactBean implements ContactLocal {


@Override
public void doSomethingWithPublicMethod(final Long id) {
    return doSomething(id)
}

ContactEntity doSomething(final Long id){
    doSomethingPrivate(id);
}

private doSomethingPrivate(final Long id){
    ...
}
```

Is the Interceptor called on all Methods, just the ones that are marked as @Override (couldn't see why it should do that) or is there any other rule? I was scanning the Java EE tutorial real quick but can't find anything describing that. May it be up to the container?

So I assume I should have all my Interceptors, Transactions etc. on the Interface and never on the Bean implementation if I want to have them working only on methods that implement the interface...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Annotations on managed beans (like EJB beans) are only processed when a call is made via a proxy. In other words, from outside the bean.

In Java it's not (easily) possible to decorate the implicit `this` variable. When you call your default and private methods from the `doSomethingWithPublicMethod` method, then no interception for these methods will take place.

Likewise, had those methods been individually annotated with say `@RunAs` or `@Asynchronous`, then these too would not be processed.

Adam Bien explained this in more detail at his blog: http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/how_to_self_invoke_ejb